# Java inheritance LuxuryCarRental

Tags: java, inheritance

I'm working on my homework assignment below (I'm still new to Java...) and I'm having some issues with figuring out the proper way to write up LuxuryCarRental.. and I'm not sure if my work for CarRental is right. I haven't gotten to UseCarRental yet.

Create a class named CarRental that contains the following fields: renterName, zipCode, carSize, rentalFee, numDaysRented, and totalRentalFee.

The class contains a constructor that requires all of the rental data except total fee, which is calculated based on the size of the car: economy at $29.99 per day, midsize at $38.99 per day, or full size at $43.50 per day.  The class also includes a display() method that display all of the rental data.

Create a subclass named LuxuryCarRental.  This class sets the rental fee at $79.99 per day.

Write an application named UseCarRental that prompts the user for the renter's name, zip code, the size of the car to rent, and the number of days they want to rent it.

Your application should display the total rental fee.

Be sure that your application test both, CarRental and LuxuryCarRental.

CarRental: https://pastebin.com/fq1wJF1s
LuxuryCarRental: https://pastebin.com/xBAK6NTy

```js
package usecarrental;

public class CarRental 
{
    private String renterName = "";
    private int rentalZipCode = 00000;
    private String rentalCarSize = "";
    private double rentalFeeDaily;
    private int numDaysRented = 0;
    private double totalRentalFee;
    
    public CarRental(String name, int zipcode, int days, String carsize)
    {
        renterName = name;
        rentalZipCode = zipcode;
        rentalCarSize = carsize;
        numDaysRented = days;
    }
    
    public void setrenterName(String name)
    {
        renterName = name;
    }
    
    public void setrentalZipCode(int zipcode)
    {
        rentalZipCode = zipcode;
    }
    
    public void setrentalCarSize(String carsize)
    {
        rentalCarSize = carsize;
    }
    
    public void setnumDaysRented(int days)
    {
        numDaysRented = days;
    }
    
    public String getrenterName()
    {
        return renterName;
    }
    
    public int getrentalZipCode()
    {
        return rentalZipCode;
    }
    
    public String getrentalCarSize()
    {
        return rentalCarSize;
    }
    
    public int getnumDaysRented()
    {
        return numDaysRented;
    }
    
    public double gettotalRentalFee()
    {
        return numDaysRented * rentalFeeDaily;
    }
    
    public double getrentalFeeDaily(String rentalCarSize)
    {
        switch (rentalCarSize)
        {
            case "Economy":
                rentalFeeDaily = 29.99;
                break;
            case "Midsize":
                rentalFeeDaily = 38.99;
                break;
            case "Fullsize":
                rentalFeeDaily = 43.50;
                break;
        }
            return rentalFeeDaily;
    }
    
    public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(
                "Customer Details" +
                "\nName          = " + getrenterName() +
                "\nZipcode       = " + rentalZipCode +
                "\nCar Size      = " + getrentalCarSize() +
                "\nRental Fee    = " + rentalFeeDaily + "/daily" +
                "\nRental Length = " + numDaysRented +
                "\nTotal Fee     + " + totalRentalFee
        );
    }
    
}


package usecarrental;

public class LuxuryCarRental extends CarRental
{
    public LuxuryCarRental(String carsize, int days)
    {
        super(carsize, days);
    }
    
    public void computetotal1()
            {
                super.computetotal(days);
                rentalFeeDaily = 79.99;
                totalRentalFee = rentalFeeDaily;
            }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read "How to create a [mcve]". Then use the [edit] link to improve your question (do not add more information via comments). Otherwise we are not able to answer your question and help you.

Comment: Hi ! Can you just explain where are you stuck in your code ? That could help us to understand and then help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Attributes And Class Constants:**

**First of all**, you don't have to assign values to your class attributes when you create them. 
Use the constructor for this purpose.

**Secondly**, those attributes should be protected as the `LuxuryCarRental` class will inherit them later.

You don't need a `rentalFeeDaily` and `totalRentalFee` attributes.

**The attributes become**

```
protected String renterName;
protected int rentalZipCode;
protected String rentalCarSize;
protected int numDaysRented;
```

You can get the `rentalFeeDaily` from the `getRentalFeeDaily()` method, and the `totalRentalFee` from the `totalRentalFee()` method.

Then put them inside the `display()` method:

```
public void display()
    {
        System.out.println(
                "Customer Details" +
                "\nName          = " + getrenterName() +
                "\nZipcode       = " + rentalZipCode +
                "\nCar Size      = " + getrentalCarSize() +
                "\nRental Fee    = " + getRentalFeeDaily + "/daily" +
                "\nRental Length = " + numDaysRented +
                "\nTotal Fee     + " + totalRentalFee
        );
    }
```

It's a better practice to make constant numbers you use in your class as **class constants.**

```
public static final double ECONOMY_FEE = 29.99;
public static final double MIDSIZE_FEE = 38.99;
public static final double FULLSIZE_FEE = 43.50;
public static final double LUXURY_FEE = 79.99;
```

In your `getRentalFeeDaily()`:

```
public double getRentalFeeDaily() {
        double rentalFeeDaily = 0;
        switch (rentalCarSize) {
        case "Economy":
            rentalFeeDaily = ECONOMY_FEE;
            break;
        case "Midsize":
            rentalFeeDaily = MIDSIZE_FEE;
            break;
        case "Fullsize":
            rentalFeeDaily = FULLSIZE_FEE;
            break;
        case "Luxury":
            rentalFeeDaily = LUXURY_FEE;

        }
        return rentalFeeDaily;
    }
```

Why did you give your `getRentalFeeDaily()` method a String parameter? your `rentalCarSize` is an attribute in your class and you can use it for the object instance accessing this method.

**LuxuryCarRental class**

A `LuxuryCarRental` *is-a-kind-of* `CarRental` with the only thing changing is the Fee.

You don't need any additional attributes for the `LuxuryCarRental` class.

```
public class LuxuryCarRental extends CarRental {

    public LuxuryCarRental(String name, int zipcode, int days) {
        super(name, zipcode, days, "Luxury");
    }

}
```

You also don't have to give a `rentalCarSize` String when creating a `LuxuryCarRental` object as you will give it yourself as "Luxury" to the super class constructor.

So later, when you create a `LuxuryCarRental` object later, and want to calculate its total fee price:

1. The constructor will give "Luxury" as a `rentalCarSize` attribute.
2. This String will be given to the method in the super class
3. The method will return the total fee after getting the luxury car fee from the `getRentalFeeDaily()` using the "Luxury" `rentalCarSize` attribute.

**UseCarRentalClass**

```
public class UseCarRental {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        CarRental cr = new CarRental("Honda", 1234, 10, "Economy");
        LuxuryCarRental lcr = new LuxuryCarRental("Jaguar", 5678, 10);

        System.out.println(cr.totalRentalFee());
        System.out.println(lcr.totalRentalFee());

    }
}
```

This should be enough as you asked.

Comment: Thank you @knoxpat so much for your help!! I'm still new to Java (literally only like my second week using it..) but I can see the errors that I've made. I just kept overthinking this and getting myself worked up over it! I'm so glad I found this site, I feel like I just learned more from you than I did my professor!

Comment: @hts95 glad i could help!